# Automated way of inserting NOP's in between of assembly instructions in MSVC

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, assembly

I would like to ask if there is any better way of inserting "NOP caves" in between of assembly instruction than doing it manually? I'll explain you what I want to achieve - I want to insert let's say after `mov` instructions some NOPped space, so I can mutate this code without dealing with fixing `jmp` offsets, I'd want to insert 5 nops or more after mov, so I can replace it with `push x; pop eax` or `xor eax, eax; add x` or other instructions. Is there any way to "automate it" other than compile time macros?

Comment: Well, that's different.  'This page intentionally left blank' :)

Comment: Are your builds really so slow that you have to consider this?

Comment: If  you 'mutate' the code image before launch, it will cause checksums/CRCs to fail and the app will not start.  If you mutate the code after its is launched, your AntiVirus package will not like it and, besides, mutating code is not thread-safe.  You must be really desperate to consider this design.

Comment: Microsoft's compiler supports generating functions that can be hotpatched. This allows the function to be replaced in its entirely by changing the first instruction to a jmp in a thread-safe manner. You need to use the /hotpatch compiler option and the /functionpadmin linker option to generate this code. (Though when targetting x64 the compiler always generates hotpatchable function.)

Comment: @MartinJames if you're referring to the checksum field in the PE Optional Header, it doesn't do anything for normal programs, changing it or the code has no consequences.

Comment: @RossRidge this is best approach so far, because I can do whatever I want to my func, but it still doesnt solve completely my problem - I wanted to put that NOPs in between of instructions, because I didnt want to fix jmp  offsets, but I think that I can manage to make it work with little help of disassembler library, anyways thanks!